# convert string to seconds

Tags: java

how can i convert string time to seconds if my hour time is greater than 24hours. My time comes from a table column

Ex:

Column Name (Late): Time (String): 00:40:00

Conversion:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss").parse($F{late}).getHours()*3600
    + new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss").parse($F{late}).getMinutes()*60
    + new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss").parse($F{late}).getSeconds();
```

OutPut: 2400

The above result is perfect but if my field value results: 31:58:00, Then my above expression is not working.

The output is : 28680

28680 is a remainder of (115080-86400)

but the actually output should be '115080'.

Comment: Well if your input is 31:58:00 then it's clearly *not* a time of day, is it? You might want to look at using Joda Time and PeriodFormat.

Comment: Yes this is not a time of one day, Sum of time.

Comment: You're attempting to use something meant for *dates / time of day* to parse something that is *not* a date / time of day. That isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to remember is there are only 24 hours in day, so your example value is actually 1d, 7 hours and 58 minutes.

Now, you could simply break the `String` down and apply simple mathamtics to calculate the time values...

```
seconds = (hours * 60 * 60) + (minutes * 60) + seconds;
```

But, where's the fun in that.  Another approach would be to use a zero based `Calendar`, for example...

```
String time = "31:58:00";
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
cal.setTimeInMillis(0);

String[] parts = time.split(":");
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(parts[0]));
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(parts[1]));
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, Integer.parseInt(parts[2]));

long millis = cal.getTimeInMillis();
long seconds = millis / 1000;
System.out.println(seconds);
```

Which essentially does the same thing but makes use of `Calendar`'s auto rolling feature.

There's probably even a really neat trick which could be used with JodaTime

**Updated with JodaTime example**

```
PeriodFormatter pf = new PeriodFormatterBuilder().
        appendHours().appendSeparator(":").
        appendMinutes().appendSeparator(":").
        appendSeconds().toFormatter();

Period period = pf.parsePeriod("31:58:00");
System.out.println(period.toStandardSeconds().getSeconds());
```

Comment: @1------- I fail to see how this is relevant

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should convert it to time of the day (i.e. 31:58:00 - 24:00:00) then calculate both and sum-up.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to All, Here is the java code what i have return

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TestDate {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
String timee="31:58:55";

DateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
// format.parse(timee).getSeconds();
int seconds = format.parse(timee).getHours()*3600+format.parse(timee).getMinutes()*60+format.parse(timee).getSeconds();

String[] parts = timee.split(":");
long millis = TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds(Long.parseLong(parts[0])) 
        + TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(Long.parseLong(parts[1])) + Long.parseLong(parts[2]);

System.out.println(millis+" in Seconds");

//System.out.println(seconds + " Converted to Seconds");
long s_hour = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(millis);
long tempSec = millis - (TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds(s_hour));
long s_minute = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(tempSec) ;
long tempSec1 = tempSec - (TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(s_minute));
long s_seconds = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(tempSec);
System.out.println(s_hour  + " in Hours");
System.out.println(tempSec+" Which is a reminder");
System.out.println(s_minute + " in Minutes");
System.out.println(tempSec1+" in Seconds");
}
}
```